# Finding time taken to complete task in a specified hour

Tags: python, datetime, dictionary

```
new = {('E_1E_2', 1.0235591568933329): [datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 25, 4, 38, 47)], 
('E_1E_2', 0.9023917716540885): [datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 25, 4, 38, 51)], 
('E_12E_2', 1.4927612857980848): [datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 25, 3, 18, 42)],
('E12_1E_2', 1.0235591568933329): [datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 25, 3, 30, 17)], 
('E_1E_2', 0.9023917716540885): [datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 25, 3, 13, 51)], 
('E_1E_2', 1.4927612857980848): [datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 25, 3, 8, 42)]}
```

This is how my data input looks like. I need to display the time taken for the students to complete the task in hourly basis. The dictionary keys consist of the student pair doing the task and the distance between the pair. The value consists of the timestamp at which they were close to each other.

```
tasktime=0
prev=datetime.datetime(1,1,1)
for i,j in new.items():
    #print(k[0],k[1])
    print(i[0],"-------------------------------------------------")
    for k,l in new.items():
        if i[0]==k[0]:
            if k[1] < 1 and len(l)==1 and j[0].hour==l[0].hour: 
                print("distance=======",k[1])
                print(l[0].hour,i[0],l)
                if (k[0],l[0]) not in sample.keys():
                    sample[k[0],l[0].hour]=0
                if prev==datetime.datetime(1,1,1):
                    prev=l[0]
                else:
                    diff=(l[0]-prev).seconds
                    tasktime=tasktime+diff
                    prev=l[0]
            elif loitime!=0 and k[1] > 1:

                print(k[0],"loitered for ",tasktime/60,"minutes")
                print("timestamp ++++++++++++++++",l[0])
```

I get the time they took for the task for the whole data and not on hourly basis.

Comment: The code snippet you posted is incomplete. What is `sample`, `loitime`? It would help to describe your problem in general, your input and expected output. The dictionary you have maybe could be constructed differently.

Comment: loitime is tasktime and sample is just an empty dictionary I attend values to

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your expected output for that data.